# Resize raster resolution with Gdal_translate or Gdalwarp

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am trying to change my resolution from 10m x10m raster cells to 25m x 25m raster cells. 
So far I figured that both `gdalwarp` and `gdal_translate` can do this (from python).

```
subprocess.call('gdal_translate -tr 25 25 -r bilinear ' + inputfile +' '+ outputfile, shell=True)
subprocess.call('gdalwarp -tr 25 25 -r bilinear ' + inputfile + ' ' + outputfile, shell=True)
```

However, I do run into 2 problems for both GDLA methods.

First problem: The output band rendering colors are shifted from hillshade to singleband grey. How can I fix this? I tried using `gdaldem` hillshade, but this did not work.

```
subprocess.call('gdal_translate -tr 25 25 -r bilinear ' + inputfile +' '+ outputfile, shell=True)
subprocess.call('gdaldem hillshade ' + outputfile + ' ' + outputfile +'_hillshade', shell=True)
```

My next problem is that the output file has extrapolated values outside of the original raster extent. See figure below.

Image of the 10m x10m resolution input raster
[image: 10m x10m resolution input raster]

Image of the 25m x25m resolution output raster - The extent of the output raster is bigger than the input raster and the raster is shown in singleband grey.
[image: 25m x25m resolution output - Extent of the output raster is bigger than the input raster]